# Is it necessary to reboot after a kernel upgrade (via APT)?

Tags: kernel, apt, upgrade

I have been wondering this for quite a while. Let's say that you have a Debian server that you keep updated via APT. Usually (every 1-2 months) there are some kernel updates, which will update the GRUB entries to boot from it next time.

This is okay, but if you care about uptime and SLA, it would be difficult to reboot just to use the updated kernel. I guess this is the usual way to go, but is it actually how it works?

Comment: Don't forget rebuilding the virtualization suite tools.

Answer (score 9):

The only method I've ever heard of that allows you to forgo performing a reboot is through the use of the [KSplice technology](http://www.ksplice.com/).

*excerpt*

> What is Ksplice Uptrack?
>
> Ksplice Uptrack lets you apply 100% of the important kernel security updates released by your Linux vendor without rebooting.
>
> Ksplice Uptrack is available for Oracle Linux, free of charge, for Oracle Linux customers with a Premier support subscription. Additionally, anyone can use Ksplice Uptrack for free on Ubuntu Desktop and Fedora.

According to the [website it's free for Fedora and Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ksplice.com/pricing) users:

*excerpt*

> Free for Fedora and Ubuntu Desktop.

#### History of technology

The KSplice technology came on the scene in 2009, if memory serves me correct. The impressive demo the technology developers used was to migrate a Linux system through all of the Linux Kernels that were ever released. I never saw the demo but that claim has stuck in my mind ever since.

Here's the Ars Technica article that I remember reading, titled: [Ksplice: Update computers without rebooting](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/07/ksplice-is-like-viagra-for-linux-server-uptime/).

Lastly here's the technical paper that covers the technology and how it works, titled: [Ksplice: Automatic Rebootless Kernel Updates](http://www.ksplice.com/doc/ksplice.pdf).

Comment: Never heard of that, that's fascinating! +1 Have to find that demo...

Comment: There are some demos on youtube, these are new ones not of the full upgrade: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1m5HJ7h1l7I

Comment: FWIW, the built-in kernel support for this is called [kexec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec).

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary in the sense that you must, it's only necessary if you *want* to use the new kernel right away.

Simply updating should never leave the system in a state whereby you must reboot after the update.  One obvious reason for this is a lot of systems update automatically, and an automatic update that screwed the running system would not be appreciated by many users.

Comment: Indeed, I am aware that you do not actually "must" do it if you do not need the new specific features/fixes of the updated kernel, however in most of the cases it is a recommended action.

Comment: **Why and by whom?**  Being slightly paranoid about software glitches is reasonable, and so if you have no reason *not* to reboot, then you should reboot, in case there is a glitch in the upgrade (of course, if there's a glitch, it could just as easily be a glitch that won't get exposed until a reboot, so...).  However, if you have a good reason not to reboot, then don't.  Of course, this leads to the obvious: if you have a good reason not to reboot, *then don't upgrade until you can*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to use an kernel update, you usually need to reboot the system. Sometimes it could be enough, to reload a kernel module - but this is difficult to decide.

By using [kexec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec), you can shorten the time the system is not available.

[Ksplice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ksplice) offers for some distributions kernel live patching.

Answer (score 0):

Is necessary? Yes, if you want the new kernel. But it can be worked around? Yes too. But then, why do we need reboot to upgrade the kernel? Because you don't reboot for anything else! Now, for the workaround you should be aware that some weirdness can (and will) happen.